# Customized sharepoint 2010 dispform cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, dispform

I would like to modify a customized dispform, however, i cannot find. I checked in All files > List > mylist but because this list contains a lot of data SP designer gives an error and I cannot load it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going to `All files > List`, Try the below alternative way to edit your Form List:

- In the browser, Open your site > Open your list > from the above ribbon > Click on `Edit List In SharePoint Designer`.

[image]

- On Forms Section > Righ click on your custom Form > Select `Edit File in Advanced Mode`.

  [image]

Comment: I tried this but the dispform in not listed there :((  Because it was customized, designer does not detecte it as dispform. thank you

Comment: You are welcome, but from where you have created your custom dis form? it should be listed here too!